# MySQL lost after upgrading to Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mysql

I made a silly mistake of upgrading Leopard a tad too soon.

I thought I dumped my mysql files but the last backup is about a month old.

Now I upgraded the computer to Snow Leopard, and trying to run the old mysql server wasn't happening. So I read you must reinstall mysql with a newer version which I did and it ran just fine and starts up just fine.

However - it seems it setup a new install, but since the older version cannot run on this platform - how can I dump the old data?

I tried mysqldump but it wasnt connecting.

Any ideas would be fantastic!

Comment: That question would better belong to Superuser.com or Serverfault.com. That's an administrative, not an programming related question.

Comment: Thanks, Ill look into those sites.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried PHPMyAdmin to work with the database and attempt an export? [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just navigate to the folder where the MySQL data is stored for the old database server, copy the directories for each database from the 'DATA' folder to the new one and then attach the databases to the new MySQL database?

Comment: what do you mean 'attach'? I can navigate to the folder and see the 'data' folder.

Comment: If Im doing this right - they are being loaded as a database, but I get  Can't read dir of './compass/' (errno: 13)

Had to change permissions to get the file, and copy them over but I reset them. Not sure how to fix this.